# Junit/Mockito how to mock an object called from class b which is called from class a

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I have a class called a, which mocks a class b.

Class b has a method which is creating an object by calling a data access object (DAO) c. That is,
`a.method1 -> b.method2` which internally calls `c.getdata()`.

When I try to create a unit test I get object c is null. How do I resolve this issue?

```java
  class Alpha {
      
    String abc;
    Beta beta = new Beta();
    List<String> seriesOfStgs = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void alphaMethod() {
        seriesOfStgs.addAll(beta.getStrings());
    }
  }

  class Beta {
      
    StringDao stringDao = new StringDao();
    
    public List<String> getStrings() {
        return stringDao.getListOfStrings();
    }
  }
```

If you see above, I have 2 separate classes `Alpha` and `Beta`. I am writing the test for `Alpha`. I am able to mock `Beta` in my JUnit test, `TestAlpha.java`.
I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to get the strings because `stringDao` is null.

How do I instantiate `stringDao` in `TestAlpha`, or how do I pass a reference to `StringDao`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by saying that class `a` "mocks a class `b`".  Can you show us some code to illustrate your point?

Comment: which class are you writing unit test for ? class A ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a way of injecting your `Beta` mock into the `Alpha` object that you're testing.  Otherwise, your `Alpha` object will just have the `Beta` that was created at the line

```
Beta beta = new Beta();
```

One way to do that would be to have a `setBeta` method in your `Alpha` class, which you could then call in your test.

Another way would be to refactor your `Alpha` class so that it gets its `Beta` object from a factory, and then inject the factory when you construct the `Alpha` object.  This is "pattern 2" in [my article here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mockito/wikis/MockingObjectCreation.wiki)

Answer (score 0):

`Beta` can be also mock object.

for example

```
@Mock
Alpha alpha;

@Mock
Beta beta;

...

when(alpha.getBeta()).thenReturn(beta);   // now you get mocked beta from alpha
when(beta.getStrings()).thenReturn("mock string");
```

Comment: it is not this simple, I have other logic in here, so I have this for the mock when(beta.getStrings()).thenAnswer((Answer<String>) invocation -> new Beta().getStrings(invocation.getArgument(0 ))); so the code is going inside that method and is throwing nullPointerException

Comment: No, if you're testing class `Alpha`, you shouldn't mock it.  You should only mock `Beta`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem You are right. That's my mistake. Alpha doesn't need to be mocked.